# If I click a link to load a different model, ,model displays then disappears. Looks like a material / component issue

Tags: reactjs, animation, three.js, react-spring, react-three-fiber

Hi Thanks in advance for your help.

The project I am developing is an adaptation of
https://codesandbox.io/s/r3f-wouter-routes-7kohn

I have split the project above into a larger project structure making use of web pack and other dependencies. My project with the bug can be viewed here:-
https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-wood-hmub1

If that codesandbox does not work for you, you can clone from here:-

- git clone https://github.com/SILVA-DIGITAL/SILVADIGITAL.git
- yarn
- yarn start

Steps to re-produce the bug:

- Click on knot or bomb ( Top right hand navigation Menu ).
- The knot or bomb model loads then disappears. Console mentions a shader error.

Known research:

- I believe the bug is found within /components/shapes/index.tsx.
- For some reason when switching the route to load a different model, the material class for the model to switch to fails its as if its not cached or does not have time to execute? I have tried wrapping the models in a suspense but that does not make a difference.

Here is the console error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All objects should be stored in useState() if they are within the render function.